# Why can't I run Ubuntu or any other distro on my PC?

Tags: installation

I have tried installing both Ubuntu 13.04 and Fedora 19, and got very stanged glitches with both. Both had very weird graphical glitches, pixels of every color appearing randomly on the screen (This seemed to be worse with Fedora, so much that i couldn't even get past the installer) I did manage to get Ubuntu installed, and, along with the colored pixles, the resolution was weird (apparently set to one higher than the max of my monitor) and I was not able to interact with anything, excluding the ability to move the mouse.

Specs:

- Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, Ubuntu 13.04
- Processor: AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core Processor, ~3.6GHz
- Memory: 8GB RAM
- Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6670+

If any other information about my system is needed please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the driver as as mentioned in this question - [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

For weird graphics, you might have some help when you boot with `nomodeset` as mentioned here.. https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/35775

So boot in nomodeset mode & then install the driver.